# Stop edit of a cell based on the value of a cell in the same row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to create create a message when a user tries to edit the date in column D when the checkbox in column E of the same row is checked. Ultimately I would like to stop the user from editing column D when column E of the same row is checked but from what I have read, I don't believe you can do this. Below is my script and I would really appreciate some help.

```js
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var sheetName = "Sheet Name";
  var row = range.getRow();
  var checkboxColumn = range.getColumn();
  var editedColumn = range.getValue();
  var checkbox = range.getValue();
  if (sheet.getName() == sheetName && editedColumn == 4 && checkboxColumn == 5 && row > 2 && checkbox == true) {
    Browser.msgBox("my message");
    }
    )
```

Comment: You should be able to achieve "blocking" of data entry using Data Validation.  On the cell that you want to restrict entry, enable Data Validation and choose the "Custom Formula" option.  The formula will be =(<checkbox cell> = FALSE).  And then select to "Reject Input".  Then test - when the checkbox is ticked and you try to enter a value you'll see a message (you can type something in, but once you move of the cell or hit Enter, the message will appear and the entry will be disallowed).  When the checkbox is unticked you'll be able to enter values.

Comment: Of course, one drawback with restricting the data entry using Data Validation is if you wanted to apply some other kind of Data Validation (like limiting to a list), then obviously you can't have multiple different rules for Data Validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can revert the value after being edited (if the checkbox in the edited row is ticked)

Also, there were some issues on your script that needs to be updated. See Craig's explanation on those issues.

#### Code:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var sheetName = "Sheet Name";
  var editedRow = range.getRow();
  var editedColumn = range.getColumn();
  var checkbox = sheet.getRange(editedRow, 5).getValue();
  if (sheet.getName() == sheetName && editedColumn == 4 && editedRow > 2 && checkbox == true) {
    Browser.msgBox("Reverting cell to original value. You can't edit this cell.");
    e.range.setValue(e.oldValue);
  }
}
```

#### Sample:

[image: sample1]
[image: sample2]
[image: sample3]

Or you can use plain old Data Validation:

#### Formula:

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN() + 1, 4)) = FALSE`

[image: output]

#### When cell is edited where checkbox is ticked:

[image: output2]

#### Note:

- I also recommend that you check Ruben's link about protection of cell. That will helpful.

Answer (score 2):

To stop a user from editing a cell, protect such cell.

Related

- [Managing Google Protected Cells in Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41617637/1595451)
- [Google sheet protect based on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59021684/1595451)
- [Protect row according to the data in cell (Yes/No)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66398119/1595451)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you can use one of the suggested methods to block data entry using the check-box value as a condition.

But, let's take a look at your actual script, so that you can understand where that's going wrong.  The parameter that's passed to the "onEdit" method has a reference to the cell being edited.  So when the user tries to edit one of the date fields (say D3), the "e" parameter is going to hold a reference to "D3" (column 4, row 3).  However, later in the function you have "var checkboxColumn = range.getColumn()".  So when your date cell is being edited, you're then trying to say that the check box column is column 4? ... that won't work.

Also, when you have "var editedColumn = range.getValue()", that is going to get the value within the cell (the date the user has entered or selected), not the column index of the cell.

Here's my suggested changes to your script

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var sheetName = "Sheet Name";
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();

  //var checkboxColumn = range.getColumn(); <-- not going to get the checkbox column when date is being edited
  //var editedColumn = range.getValue(); 
  //var checkbox = range.getValue();
  //if (sheet.getName() == sheetName && editedColumn == 4 && checkboxColumn == 5 && row > 2 && checkbox == true) {
    //Browser.msgBox("my message");
    //}

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetName && col == 4 && row > 2)
  {
      // only run further logic if we know that the date column is being edited
      //
      // use getRange() to get the relative check-box cell, one column over, and then its value
      //
      if (sheet.getRange(row, (col + 1)).value == true) // the check-box (column 5) is ticked
      {
          Brower.msgBox("my message");
      }
  }
    )
```

Comment: That makes sense - Thank you for your help